# Integration of PDF's to find valid constant

Tags: probability, integration, density-function

I'm studying probability theory and came across and exercise problem that I would like to ask help with. Here's the specific problem that is in question:

Let $X$ and $Y$ have joint PDF

$$f_{X, Y}(x, y) = cxy$$
for $(0 \lt x \lt y \lt 1)$. Find $c$ to make this a valid PDF.

It's honestly a simple problem, but I am struggling to grasp some techniques regarding the integration of the joint PDF, which is leading me to get an incorrect answer.

**My approach**

Since a PDF must integrate to $1$ and must be nonnegative in order to be valid,

\begin{align}
\int \int f_{X, Y}(x, y) & = \int_{y=x}^{y=1} \int_{x=0}^{x=y} cxy\ dxdy \\
& = \int_{y=x}^{y=1}\frac{c}{2}y^3dy \\
& = \frac{c(1-x^4)}{8}
\end{align}

Therefore, I concluded that $c = \frac{8}{1-x^4}$. However, the solution that I was given has taken a different approach of switching the order of integration and also using different integration limits, leading to a completely different result.

**Correct solution**

\begin{align}
\int \int f_{X, Y}(x, y) & = \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \left( \int_{y=x}^{y=1} cxy\ dy \right) dx \\
& = \int_{x=0}^{x=1} \frac{cx-cx^3}{2} dx \\
& = \frac{c}{4} \\
\end{align}

This gives us $c = 4$.

I have two specific questions:

1. Why did the correct solution switch the order of integration?
2. The limits of integration that I set were based on the initial condition of $(0 \lt x \lt y \lt 1)$. That's why I had the limits for $x$ set to $x = 0$ and $x = y$. However, the correct solution set it to $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. Why is this so? Is there something that I missed?

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**

The "correct" solution is actually incorrect. The last integral calculation should give us $\frac{c}{8}$, leading us to $c = 8$, not $4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your integral needs to reflect the constraints $ 0 < x,y <1$ and $x<y$. If you think about it, this means that x could take any value in (0,1) and moreover, for any such x, y can take any value in (x,1) and that’s why your solution is not correct and their solution is.
In your solution you are fixing x, but what even is the value of x you are fixing it to?

Comment: That's what I initially thought, but if we take into account the constraint that $x \lt y$, then wouldn't it make more sense to set the integration limit as $y$? I'm having trouble understanding why $x$ would be able to take on any value in interval $(0, 1)$ when it's constrained by the value of $y$.

Comment: Are you saying that because the value of $y$ is not yet determined, $x$ may take on any value in $(0, 1)$?

Comment: x is bounded by y, but y is free to move within (0,1)

Comment: Also, if you like you could set the limits of x from 0 to y, but then you’d have to set the limits of y from 0 to 1 to get a correct answer

Comment: I think I understand your point. I believe that due to the fact that we must consider the value of $y$ first, we switched the order of integration. However, what I'm still wondering is why we set the limit of integration for $x$ to be from $(0, 1)$, because as you said $y$ is free to move within $(0, 1)$, but $x$'s range is $(0, y)$. I hope I am making sense.

Comment: You don’t have to consider the value of y first. You can consider either the value of x first, in which case y is constrained to be between x and 1 or you could consider y first and then x is constrained to be within 0 and y and you get two perfectly equivalent solutions

Comment: What matters is that the set {$0<x<y<1$} can be written as {$0<x<1$, $x<y<1$}

Comment: I think I understand now. If I understand correctly, we can either write $\{0 \lt x \lt 1,\ x \lt y \lt 1\}$ or $\{0 \lt x \lt y,\ 0 \lt y \lt 1\}$ right?

Comment: Yes, absolutely ;)

Comment: I've tried with different limits, and I'm getting a different answer. I'm not sure what the problem is. :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85977/discussion-between-sorin-tirc-and-sean).